# Hawkbit server doesn't work after few hours online

Tags: docker, docker-compose, eclipse-hawkbit, hawkbit

I have an hawkbit server behind a traefik proxy running on docker-compose

```
mysql:
  image: "mysql:latest"
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: "hawkbit"
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "true"
  restart: always
  ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
    mysql-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
  labels:
    NAME: "mysql"
  networks:
    hawkbit-network

hawkbit:
  image: "hawkbit/hawkbit-update-server:latest-mysql"
  environment:
      - 'SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mariadb://mysql:3306/hawkbit'
      - 'SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq'
      - 'SPRING_RABBITMQ_USERNAME=guest'
      - 'SPRING_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=guest'
      - 'SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root'
  volumes:
    artifactrepo:/artifactrepo
  restart: always
  ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  depends_on:
    mysql
  labels:
    NAME: "hawkbit"
    traefik.enable: true
    traefik.http.routers.hawkbit.rule: Host(`hawkbit.domain`)
    traefik.http.routers.hawkbit.entrypoints: hawkbit
    traefik.docker.network: docker-files_traefik-network
    traefik.http.services.hawkbit.loadbalancer.server.port: 8080
  networks:
    hawkbit-network
    traefik-network


volumes:
  mysql-db-data:
    driver: local
  artifactrepo:
    driver: local


networks:
  traefik-network:
  hawkbit-network:
```

Right after the building of the docker compose, everything works fine, I have access to the UI, can connect, save parameters.

But after few hours, hawkbit seems to lost the connection to the database

```
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 1049
Message    : (conn=82) Unknown database 'hawkbit'

at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:60)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:75)
at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:147)
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:124)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
115 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=82) Unknown database 'hawkbit'
```

When I look with docker ps, I see the uptime of mysql container have few hours less than the hawkbit one.

So it's seems to be a volume problems, as mysql container has been rebooted and can't find data.

It's confirmed when I try to restart mysql container, hawkbit one, and both without result, but removing mysql volume and restart both works and it's up for few jours before crashing again.

I don't see where I made a mistake on volume declaration, can it be another problem?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is narrowly focused on software development questions, which is to say, questions about _writing code_. For system administration and operational questions, [unix.se] is a better choice.

Comment: That said -- did you read the logs for the mysql container? Read those logs, and keep an eye on resource use -- if something has memory (or tmpfs, or other limited-resource) requirements that grow over time and eventually trigger an OOM, that's an easy way to get this kind of problem.

Comment: There are also tools you can use to get a recording of what happened around the time of the event; for example, [sysdig](https://github.com/draios/sysdig) ships with a chisel (an event filter built in lua) that lets you tell it to retain a complete trace of everything that happened on your system (across both containers!) near the time of the SQLSyntaxErrorException being thrown (assuming you can write a filter that triggers on that event -- which should be very straightforward).

Comment: See https://sysdig.com/blog/sysdig-plus-logs/ for a blog post describing the functionality in question.

Comment: Sounds like a memory issue. How much RAM and swap space do you have on the host machine?